# Installing site using custom profile gives error "call to undefined function libraries_get_path"

Tags: 7, theming, installation-profiles

I have to change an already made site. It is using a different custom made Profile and not the standard profile. but when I install it, it gives error "Call to undefined function libraries_get_path on line 5 in my custom module."

How can I solve this error?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you turned on the libraries module?

Comment: Shouldn't the site automatically enable it while installation? It gives error while installation.

Comment: I would first check if that module is on before proceeding

Comment: You didn't get me. I am saying I am selecting the custom profile during installation, which means the site is not yet installed. The installation process should enable the module. I can check it only if it's installed but the site doesn't get installed.